# No puedo ver mapa en un ion tab con ionic 4

Tags: ionic, typescript, gps

Estoy tratando de crear una app en ionic 4 en  la cual se navegue con ion tabs. El problema está en que debo mostrar un mapa dentro del ion tab y ni siquiera me toma  las coordenadas. Estoy usando el api en javascript  de  google. La app compila bien pero no muestra el mapa, ya  cambié las  dimensiones del css  pero aun así no muestra nada.

Código ts del tab 1:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions ,Geoposition ,PositionError } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';

declare  var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: './tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab1.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab1Page implements OnInit {

  constructor(

       private geolocation: Geolocation

  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }
  async loadmap(){

   const respuesta = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();

    const myLatLng = {
     lat: respuesta.coords.latitude,
     lng: respuesta.coords.longitude
    }; 
    console.log(myLatLng);
    const mapEle: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('mapa');
    // create map
      const map = new google.maps.Map(mapEle, {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 12
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Verifica que en tus estilos le estes dando el ancho y alto adecuado a tu mapa.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

No se podia  observar  el mapa  debido  a que   el  id  de la etiqueta div que se usa en el  page.html  no era el mismo,  por otro  lado    al utilizar elgetelemenbyid tambien estaba distinto

Comment: Podrias mirar [answer]? tu respuesta se reporto como de baja calidad, ya que no se entiende bien cual fue el problema y cual es la solucion.